# How can I detect an edge swipe (touch) with pure JS?

Tags: javascript, web, touch, swipe, material-components

I am creating a webapp using [MDC-Web](https://www.github.com/material-components/material-components-web) and I decided to add a left edge swipe to open the drawer. The problem is that I can't find any good solution by searching on the internet using at the same time pure JS and edge swiping (not swiping anywhere on the screen, only from the edge). If you have any solution that uses pure JS and edge swipe, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you done any research yet? Looked into touch event handlers? Because you're supposed to do that before asking a question here.

Comment: Yes, I did. I found a swipe that works with touch but the problem is that you can swipe anywhere on the screen and it triggers, I want it to activate only if swiped from the edge. http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents2.shtml

Comment: Did you try adding a coordinate check to it? Extend the code to store the swipe's starting x coordinate, and after the code has detected a right swipe, check for `startX` being less than 20 or so. There's your left edge swipe.

Comment: Could you please provide a little code for that? I'm not sure I can make it work... Thank you!!

Comment: Feel free to edit this fiddle if it's easier for you 
 https://jsfiddle.net/ueojvdjq/3/

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/jv3n1e8t/ (untested)

Comment: I actually made it myself! Thank you!!